# Unable to run TestSuite(which contains all junit test classes) in run mode

Tags: java, debugging, junit, test-suite

I am unable to run my TestSuite (which contains nearly 100 JUnit test files) in run mode, but I am able to run all those in debug mode successfully. If I do in run mode some tests are passing remaining all are failed. Please help me out in this regard. Please let me know If any other information is necessary.